# access deny on plesk server mvc site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, plesk

Access to the path 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\teritapayateb.com\httpdocs\Images\Slider\' is denied.
I set permission allow all but also appear this error 
in my code upload image worked correctly but when i delete my image this error show.
and in plesk i have (Application pool group (IWPG_teritapa))
how i  solve it?
Access to the path 'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\teritapayateb.com\httpdocs\Images\Slider\' is denied.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31NuA.png)

Comment: How did you set the permission?

Comment: in advance setting i add full control on my image folder

Comment: It looks like your web host does not allow you to make a folder "write" enabled. You will need to contact them.